# How can you produce sharp paint results when rotating a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, transform, transformation, interpolation, bufferedimage

One attempted approach was to use `TexturePaint` and `g.fillRect()` to paint the image. This however requires you to create a new TexturePaint and Rectangle2D object each time you paint an image, which isn't ideal - and doesn't help anyway.

When I use `g.drawImage(BufferedImage,...)`, the rotated images appear to be blurred/soft.

I'm familiar with *RenderingHints* and double-buffering (which is what I'm doing, I think), I just find it difficult to believe that you can't easily and efficiently rotate an image in Java that produces sharp results.

Code for using `TexturePaint` looks something like this.

```
Grahics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 
g2d.setPaint(new TexturePaint(bufferedImage, new Rectangle2D.Float(0,0,50,50)));
g2d.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
```

I'm using `AffineTransform` to rotate a hand of cards into a fan. 
What would be the best approach to paint good-looking images quickly?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Example of blurred rotations]

*The 9 is crisp but the rest of the cards are definitely not as sharp.*

It could be possible that the problem lies in when I create each card image and store it in an array. 

Here's how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
// i from 0 to 52, card codes.
...
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
BufferedImage img = gc.createCompatibleImage(86, 126, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);

    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
    setRenderingHints(g);
    g.drawImage(shadow, 0, 0, 86, 126, null);
    g.drawImage(white, 3, 3, 80, 120, null);
    g.drawImage(suit, 3, 3, 80, 120, null);
    g.drawImage(value, 3, 3, 80, 120, null);
    g.dispose();

    cardImages[i] = img;
}

private void setRenderingHints(Graphics2D g){
    g.setRenderingHint(KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
}
```

How should I approach this differently?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
[image: Example of hand without RenderingHints]

*Without RenderingHints*

Setting AA hints made no difference. Also, setting *RenderingHints* when creating the images makes no difference either. It's only when they are being rotated with `AffineTransform` and painted using `g.drawImage(...)` that they seem to blur. 
The image above shows the difference between default (nearest neighbor) and bilinear interpolation.

Here is how I'm currently painting them (much faster than TexturePaint):

```
// GamePanel.java
private void paintCard(Graphics2D g, int code, int x, int y){
    g.drawImage(imageLoader.getCard(code), x, y, 86, 126, null);
  }

// ImageLoader.java
public BufferedImage getCard(int code){
    return cardImages[code];
  }
```

All my cards are 80x120 and the shadow .png is 86x126, so as to leave 3px semi-transparent shadow around the card. It's not a realistic shadow I know, but it looks okay.

And so the question becomes... *How can you produce sharp paint results when rotating a BufferedImage?*

Reference to a previous question also regarding a fanned card hand:
[How can you detect a mouse-click event on an Image object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577227/how-can-you-detect-a-mouse-click-event-on-an-image-object-in-java)

**Bounty-Edit:**
Okay so after much discussion I made a few test .svg cards to see how SVG Salamander would go about rendering them. Unfortunately, the performance is terrible. My implementation is clean enough, seeing as with double-buffered BufferedImage's the painting was incredibly fast. Which means I have come full circle and I'm back to my original problem.

I'll give the 50 bounty to whoever can give me a solution to get sharp BufferedImage rotations. Suggestions have been to make the images bigger than they need to be and downscale before painting, and to use bicubic interpolation. If these are the only possible solutions, then I really don't know where to go from here and I may just have to deal with the blurred rotations - because both of those impose performance setbacks.

I can finish my game if I can find a way to do this well. 
Thanks to everyone. :)

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the `RenderingHints`.

Comment: @Moonbeam: RenderingHints won't help with images, but rather only with shapes that we draw. If you look at the API, it states: "*The ANTIALIASING hint controls whether or not the geometry rendering methods of a Graphics2D object will attempt to reduce aliasing artifacts along the edges of shapes.*" So he is right not to even try to use them here.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eeels, I'm not sure if that's true. I'm pretty sure that `drawImage(...)` uses `RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION`, with `NEAREST_NEIGHBOR` being the default hint.

Comment: @HoverCraft Full Of Eels: RenderingHints definitely affect images too. Although I'm starting to see a difference between filling a shape with a TexturePaint, and actually just drawing an image. What that difference might be I do not know, and would like to find out.

Comment: @Rudi: I should clarify, and rather than make a blanket statement about all RenderingHints, say instead that as far as I know `RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON` does not result in anti-aliasing of images.

Comment: @Moonbeam: Edited the question to show how I'm implementing RenderingHints. I "create" the images in my ImageLoader, and grab them from the array when I want them in my game's main panel. In this panel I'm using the ImageLoader's setRenderingHints() method. If that makes sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you detect a mouse-click event on an Image object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577227/how-can-you-detect-a-mouse-click-event-on-an-image-object-in-java)

Comment: doesn't too much blur mean too much antialiasing?

Comment: @Hovercraft: Okay I'll take your word for it. :) Although interpolation hints would affect images? And what about when you fill shapes - surely then AA would affect the filled shape?

Comment: @guido Yes it would, in which case the reason for my images blurring isn't AA or the lack of it, but instead how I'm using BufferedImage. At first I thought it could be upscaling, but that's definitely not the case either.

Comment: @Rudi, I think you're overriding your rendering hint, such that the only rendering hint set is `KEY_ANTIALIASING`. You should be invoking `addRenderingHints(...)`, if you want multiple rendering hints.

Comment: @Moonbeam: That would actually make a ridiculous amount of sense. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Moonbeam: to my knowledge hints work like a map, so you set a different value for each key

Comment: @Rudi: what if you keep bigger in memory images, and downscale after rotating just before visualization?

Comment: @guido: That's correct it seems; that there's no difference between setting it three times the way I did and adding a new RenderingHints object the another and then setting that as the g2d's RH object.

Comment: @guido: That could be something I could try, but surely this can be done without the need to do up- and downscaling?

Comment: @guido, You're right. I misinterpreted the method. But regardless, before you do any image drawing, just set the `KEY_INTERPOLATION` rendering hint.

Comment: @Rudi: don't take my word on it as this is according to my understanding of things but is certainly not the gospel. I'm awaiting verification by the Java graphics gurus.

Comment: @trashgod: I disagree strongly -- this post is not close to being a duplicate of the one linked to in your comment. I'd protect this post if I could and will offer a bounty if no decent answer has been provided within the requisite period.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: The only thing in common with my other question was the fact that it's still the same game/similar screenshot. Looking forward to figuring out what's going on here. Can share more code if I need to.

Comment: @paranoid: I agree. My comment was to trashgod who voted to close this thread as a possible duplicate.

Comment: @Hovercraft: Haha I know, was agreeing with you. :) Cheers.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Your point is well taken, but I'm unsure how [protection](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) would help. I would encourage @paranoid-android to edit this question to cite the previous question for reference.

Comment: @guido: At the moment downscaling seems to be working quite well. :)

Comment: @paranoid-android rotating an image by an arbitrary angle means destroying data; the bigger the image the less data you lose, so it could be the only option if you cannot afford switching to vector graphics

Comment: @guido The only reason why I can't seem to afford vector graphics is because I couldn't get it to not "render" every time I want to paint it. I suppose I could render it to a BufferedImage first and then paint that, but with animation and constant angle changes, this simply wouldn't be efficient. If you want, hit me up with an answer suggesting up- and downscaling and I'll accept it as an answer seeing as it solved my problem better than any other suggestion has.

Comment: @paranoid-android as i only gave an hint and no implementation, it's better if you answer yourself with some sample code and accept that. Note i didn't suggest upscaling (it's lossy), only to keep bigger images and scale down just before visualization

Comment: @guido: That's what I meant by upscaling, which I now realise is the wrong term to be using. I'll type up an answer for it, thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you rotate a rasterized image (such as a BufferedImage), you lose data. The best solution is to save your images larger than you'll need them, and downscale on the fly when you paint them. I've found that 1.5x the size you need is a good starting point.

Then, when you're painting the image, resize on the fly:

```
g.drawImage(bufferedImage, x, y, desiredWidth, desiredHeight, observer);
```

Rotations using **bilinear interpolation** is recommended.

*Credit for suggestion goes to guido.*

Answer (score 5):

This advice is probably a little late in your design, but may be worth mentioning.

Rasterized images is probably the wrong technology to use if a lot of rotations and animations are a part of your UI; especially with complicated images with lots of curves.  Just wait until you try and scale your canvass. I might suggest looking at a vector based graphical library. They will render the sorts of effects you want with less potential for artifacts.

[http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.htm](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll consider that approach next time. In actual fact my game is scalable and all the widths and heights and positions are relative to the panel size. I have checked them and the cards are being drawn at the right size. In the example above I just hardcoded the sizes so as to fit 1280x720, the default panel size.

Comment: @paranoid: I think I've seen public domain SVG image playing cards somewhere, so there are appropriate images already available for you. Let me see if I can find them again. **Edit:** here are some: [svg-cards](http://svg-cards.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Due to the lack of support/solid answers, I'm going to redesign my deck of cards at paths and export to SVG files, then use Batik to transcode/render. If this approach works well, I will accept your suggestion as the answer. Give me a few days.

Comment: @paranoid: it's not my suggestion but mbarnes, but regardless, yes, accept it if it works. Best of luck!

Comment: @mbarnes I'm finding Batik quite tricky to use. I may ask a new question regarding its use.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the interpolation type, as well as anti-aliasing value, in an [`AffineTransformOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html) may offer some improvement. Type `TYPE_BICUBIC`, while slower, is typically the best quality; an example is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage/4216635#4216635). Note that you can supply multiple [`RenderingHints`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html). Another pitfall arises from failing to apply the hints each time the image is rendered. You may also need to adjust the transparency of the background, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500). Finally, consider creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that includes one of your actual images.

Comment: I'll create an sscce today, because AffineTransformOp didn't seem to do anything differently - assuming I used it right. Where and how do I post/share the sscce? Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your question, paste the code, select it, click the `{}` icon, and save the edited question. There's an icon for images, too. As the behavior of `RenderingHints` is suggestive in nature, your host OS and Java platform versions may be relevant.

Comment: Ah hopefully what I did isn't too far off? See edits. Thanks.

Comment: I posted a screenshot [here](http://i56.tinypic.com/oaao43.png). I see a clear benefit to anti-aliasing or bicubic interpolation, although platforms may vary.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see a slight improvement as well with bicubic, but the rendering is so slow that it's really not worth it. What I might do is consider making the image files larger and downscale before a paint them.

Comment: @paranoid-android, You should look into [Progressive Bilinear Scaling](http://books.google.com/books?id=FRbVIYAimp0C&pg=PT155&lpg=PT155&dq=java,+progressive+bilinear+scaling,+filthy+rich+clients&source=bl&ots=Yo-25qLzLO&sig=4vFng7x_23lScewqQYqGT6OiqCc&hl=en&ei=cRYoTs6vBcWBgAf4pbRc&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)