# How can I use an image as a button in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, imagebutton

I'm using netbeans to create a project app and I'm trying to get a custom image file to act as a button, I heard somewhere set it as a label instead but I'm quite new to this so I need an in depth answer on how to do this. The website won't let me post an image of the button because I'm only new but the button is in the shape of a triangle.

Comment: Start by reading the JButton API and you will find a link on `How to Use Buttons...` which contains a working example.

Answer (score 4):

Use methods [implemented in API and to remove Borders and Background from `JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html).

e.g.

[image]   [image]

from code

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyToggleButton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

    public MyToggleButton() {
        final JButton toggleButton = new JButton();
        toggleButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        toggleButton.setBorder(null);
        toggleButton.setFocusable(false);
        toggleButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        toggleButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        toggleButton.setIcon((errorIcon));
        toggleButton.setSelectedIcon(infoIcon);
        toggleButton.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        toggleButton.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        add(toggleButton);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyToggleButton t = new MyToggleButton();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) that mixes buttons & labels.

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825123/event-detection-on-opaque-pixels-in-jbutton/13825593#13825593) example for creating buttons using transparent images and allowing clicks only on non-transparent pixels.